# pandas groupby multiply and sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
id  x  y
1   3  5
1   4  2
2   5  6
2   3  3
```

Now I want to groupby id column and multiply `x` and `y` and then find its sum in a new column `z`, like so:

```
id  x  y  z
1   3  5  23
1   4  2  23
2   5  6  39
2   3  3  39
```

here, 23 = 3*5 + 4*2 and 39 = 5*6 + 3*3

This is what I tried:

```
df2 = df.copy()
group = df.groupby('id')
df2['z'] = (group['x']*group['y']).sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it is throwing me this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'SeriesGroupBy' and
> 'SeriesGroupBy'

Comment: `df["z"] = df["x"].mul(df["y"]).groupby(df["id"]).transform("sum")`

Comment: @user3483203 thing is I have to do this for a lot of columns so I dont want to perform groupby everytime. Can I instead you the groupby object called `group`?